# When and why to use aliased name or its class name in c#?

Tags: c#, oop

Why and when should we use `int`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64`, `double`, `string` instead of `Int`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Double`, `String` respectively? I have ready many articles about this but still not getting a proper solution.

Comment: They are C# *keywords*, not identifier aliases.  Keywords help a language parser to recover from syntax errors and isolate the language from the runtime implementation details.  Things you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter at all in *implementation*. I personally prefer using the aliases, and from what I've seen of other code that's the more common choice. There are some who suggest using the BCL names (`Int32` etc) everywhere though - including Jeffrey Richter, author of CLR via C# (where he gives that advice).

However, when you're naming methods and types, you should use the BCL name rather than the C#-specific name. That way your code is equally idiomatic to people using your code from other languages. This is the convention adopted within the BCL itself. For example, we have `Convert.ToInt32` and `Convert.ToSingle` instead of `Convert.ToInt` and `Convert.ToFloat`.

While it doesn't matter in theory if those are internal or private members, I'd suggest getting in the habit of giving your members the names you'd want to expose publicly - it means you can be consistent there regardless of access, and you're less likely to accidentally let one slip through.

Answer (score 5):

This is purely a matter of preference/tradition.

[C# language specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) states:

> Each of the predefined types is shorthand for a system-provided type. For example, the keyword int refers to the struct System.Int32. As a matter of style, use of the keyword is favoured over use of the complete system type name.

Comment: It's correct only for the 3rd and 4th editions of C# Language Specification. The most recent [5th edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf) doesn't contain this claim. They rewrote the paragraph about aliases of simple types. Here it is how it looks now:  
  
_C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types. The simple types are identified through keywords, but these keywords are simply aliases for predefined struct types in the System namespace, as described in the table below_.

Comment: Ahh fair enough, thanks for linking the new version of the specification.

Answer (score 1):

It truly does not matter, just be consistent. I personally use the original, lowercase names.